# How to import or extend existing CRS (CommerceReferenceStore) project into eclipse

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo

I have successfully installed ATG10.2 and deployed CRS using CIM.
Now i want to import CRS Project into eclipse.

But i am unable to import it.

Please help me to import into eclipse (elipse ATG Plugin already installed).

Answer (score 2):

This is a common tweak, I use it. If you are able to create a new ATG web module then you would be able to do this too.

Create a test application from your atg plugin, and copy its .classpath and .project files to the CommerceReferenceStore Folder under ATG root directory, don't forget to change the name of the project in the .project file. You can change the classpath after importing the project to eclipse.

then go to eclipse and import an already existing project (without using atg plugin), you are good to go.

If you want to get the individual modules as projects, add these two files to the individual modules and import them to eclipse.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Install the Eclipse plugin from %DYNAMO_ROOT%\Eclipse folder. Then add new exusting ATG project.